# Asp.Net Boilerplate Notifications

Tags: asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

I have Notifications working in a .NET Core web application using the Abp Boilerplate framework.  I've also implemented EmailRealTimeNotifier so that after the Push notification is sent, an Email is sent as well.

I'd like to give Users of the application the ability to choose as a preference, whether they want to receive

1. Push Notifications Only
2. Email Notifications Only
3. Both Push and Email Notifications

I figure I can refactor the EmailRealTimeNotifier class used to send Emails with some clever logic hopefully. But I'm stuck on where and or how I would implement code to prevent the Push Notification from firing off.

Answer (score -1):

You can save the settings in the Settings per user provided by abp, read those settings and based on that send the emails or push notifications.